# So why aren't supercapacitors used more often?

Tags: power, capacitor, power-electronics, supercapacitor

I've recently found out that supercapacitors (C >= 1F or so) are actually a thing.

I went searching for their advantages and disadvantages.

- They don't hold as much energy as a battery, but can endure many charge and discharge cycles.
- They have a lower inner resistance, so they can output a great current.
- Also they're not cheap, but they're not prohibitively expensive either.

From what i gather, they could be a great solution for many problems, and yet, they are rare and I've never seen them around.

Why is that? They seem so good. What's the catch?

Comment: *they could be a great solution for many problems* - try listing ten.

Comment: ten is a bit overkill, but for one i think they could serve as a good backup power supply, for peak currents, instead of using a overdimensioned battery or power circuits

Comment: The biggest catch is that the voltage drops (a lot!) when you try to use it as replacement for a battery.

Comment: Oldfart. Huh that's unexpected. How is that?

Comment: OK then list 5.

Comment: Because they are big, expensive and hold very little charge (compared to a battery).

Comment: @Dr.Zuipperpips The voltage drops a lot because that's how capacitors work. Electrochemical batteries keep a fairly constant voltage as they discharge until they're completely dead, but capacitor voltage is directly proportional to their state of charge.

Comment: i'll list one more and that's what you get, yer silly goof.
They could be also a good portable power supply for shutting down safely if the main power supply is cut. Say i have this sweet sweet 3dprinter, but the main power has been cut. I could just retract the filament a bit, reposition the extruder and save the last command in non volatile memory before it shuts down.

Comment: Or just use a battery that costs a fraction of what a supercapacitor costs.

Comment: They are not as rare as you may think (look up regenerative braking for one example) but one of the drawbacks is that for most devices, the temperature range is limited; I know of only one company whose devices are rated to (and tested to) +85C. Most have rather poor self discharge characteristics above 60C.

Comment: @PeterSmith to be fair, this is also a problem with the various lithium batteries. At the other end are the fun molten salt batteries that don't work below 500C.

Comment: 1 Farad? That is so 80s (we used them as memory backup in mobile radios at the time and a common one was 4F). Take a look at these (up to 3000F) https://ioxus.com/english/products/technology/

Comment: @PeterSmith thanks for that link - leading to the fascinating subject of hybrid gantry cranes https://www.maritime-executive.com/article/hybrid-gantry-cranes-a-closer-look

Comment: Supercaps are only good for *short-term* energy storage due to their high leakage (self-discharge.) Where a typical flashlight battery may last 5 years in storage, a supercap would be useless in a few months. So no, supercaps are not a replacement for batteries.

Comment: "They can output a great current" can either be an awesome feature or a catastrophic safety problem, depending on your application.

Comment: Ordinary capacitors are already used for graceful shutdown. A lot of high speed USB drives for example can fully flush their RAM buffers when you pull out the USB cable. But for a demanding application like retracting a 3d printer filament even a very beefy supercapacitor will only power the motors for half a second or so - maybe that's enough. Supercaps are indeed used for such things. But half a second of power (or if not using much current then 10 seconds of power) cannot beat batteries that can run minutes or hours

Answer (score 14):

- Low energy density: for a given amount of energy, they take up more space than almost all battery technologies
- High leakage: [this document has some nice curves.](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/KEMETSupercap_Leakage_Selfdischarge-Q3FY18.pdf) It looks like they've lost half the voltage after a week.
- Bad discharge curves: normal batteries might give you 80% of the power before they've dropped 20% voltage. Capacitors give out power evenly across their exponential curve. So either you end up using a small amount of the capacity before the voltage drops too low for your application, or you need to mess around with boost converters on the output to keep it matched.

Edit: Peter Smith's link highlights some good applications. They're not widely used in *cars* yet because of the density and leakage issues, but for industrial equipment they're a good fit.

Comment: Bit early to flag this as answered, other people might want to contribute too!

Comment: Regarding leakage, that document has graphs showing voltage and current separately, but wouldn't stored energy be the more useful metric? If supercaps "lost half the voltage", I would think it should be possible to rig up a voltage regulator to keep the output roughly stable.

Comment: @pjc50 Nothing them from doing prevents them from doing so.

Answer (score 9):

The meaning of the term *supercapacitor* has changed over time.

In the 1980s, it referred to devices designed for very low current memory backup power and they had a relatively low output current capability (high ESR). I remember one that was 4F, 5V in a relatively small package but had a current capability of perhaps 10mA.

Newer devices have low (and sometimes *really* low) ESR and very high working current capability. They typically also are low voltage (often 2.7V) so a practical application uses a series - parallel arrangement.

Take [this family](https://ioxus.com/files/5515/8507/8902/DataSheet_60mm_Cells_200316.pdf) for example:

Capacitance up to 3000F, DC ESR nominally around 250\$\mu \Omega\$, 1 second peak current measured in thousands of amps but a limited temperature range to get datasheet operation.

In applications such as [regenerative braking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_brake) (becoming more common particularly in hybrid and all electric vehicles), where hundreds (or more) of amps may flow during the braking event, they act as a perfect energy store to later be used to recharge the onboard batteries. The primary batteries could not take that as charge in direct form.

But, as noted by pjc50, there are downsides as well.

As with all technologies, they will be used where they best fit the requirement, and currently that is not really high.

I was evaluating them as a potential form of back up for power drop out in avionics (which was never finished due to lack of time and the fact that the temperature range was a bit suspect for that application) but that is a bit of a niche application (perhaps a few 10s of thousands of systems a year which is hardly the numbers manufacturers want to see).

So they are used, but until they start to approach battery densities they will be a niche product and even then the circuitry around them (to deal with the charge / discharge voltages) will have to become a lot less expensive.

Comment: The car battery buffer is an interesting application which I didn't know about. It really uses the advantages and avoids all disadvantages of supercapacitors. (They remind me a bit of the SSD "front end" of a hybrid hard disk...)

Answer (score 5):

Supercaps are really a compromise between a regular cap and a battery. And, as every compromise, they can't fully match any of the  alternatives.

If you can live with a battery it's better to use one. 500000 recharge cycles on a [typical](http://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electronic-components/resources/data-sheet/eaton-xt-supercapacitors-cylindrical-cells-data-sheet.pdf) supercap look impressive unless you check out the lifetime: 1500 hours. That's right: if you keep it fully charged at 65°C, it will last a couple of months. Not to mention the low energy density.

If you can live with an elco, you don't want a supercap either. Not only you are free to chose any voltage you like, and keep the elco fully charged, but you also get lifetime and temperature ratings which are simply unavailable in supercaps. For instance, try finding a supercap rated for [> 100°C](http://www.vishay.com/doc?49487) (typical requirement for engine compartment electronics).

So, you'd only use a supercap in applications where you can't put a battery and can't put an elco either. Presumably, there aren't that many.

Comment: What is an "elco"? It's one of those terms that doesn't give a lot of useful results.

Comment: @Daffy Electrolytic capacitor, from the older term "electrolytic condenser" that is still used in some languages.

Comment: Well, yes, 1,500h **at max temperature.** But [10 years](https://www.capcomp.de/fileadmin/Webdata/partner/SPSCAP/Datasheet_module/Data-Sheet_MCE0060C0-0015R0TBF_2017-1_EN.pdf) at room temperature. A short-lived capacitor could not be used in a UPS buffer where it must be permanently charged.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The max temperature is only 65°C. Many cellphones get over 50°C when charging or in intensive use.

Comment: @Daffy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elco